# add xml parent node from element attribute

Tags: xml, xslt

I am very new to transform files. I need to add a parent node based on the name attribute.  Here's a starting sample:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<NCD_v2>
<ReportHost name="IPv4">
    <HostProperties>
    <tag name="t1">stuff</tag>
    <tag name="t2">junk</tag>
    <tag name="t3">more stuff</tag>
</HostProperties>
<ReportItem attrib1="0" atrib2="general">
    <tag name="t1">stuff</tag>
    <tag name="t2">junk</tag>
    <tag name="t3">more stuff</tag>
</ReportItem>
</ReportHost>
</NCD_v2>
```

What I want is to read the name attribute from ReportHost and add that as the parent:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<NCD_v2>
<IPv4>
<ReportHost name="IPv4">
    <HostProperties>
    <tag name="t1">stuff</tag>
    <tag name="t2">junk</tag>
    <tag name="t3">more stuff</tag>
</HostProperties>
<ReportItem attrib1="0" atrib2="general">
    <tag name="t1">stuff</tag>
    <tag name="t2">junk</tag>
    <tag name="t3">more stuff</tag>
</ReportItem>
</ReportHost>
</IPv4>
</NCD_v2>
```

I am sure this is very basic, but so am I at this point.

Thanks, in advance!
CS

Comment: maybe a more direct route would be to replace ReportHost node name with the attribute value.

Comment: Start with an identity transform.  Add a template for `<ReportHost>` elements that emits the needed containing element around the `<ReportHost>` and its contents.  Details left as an exercise.